# Always pass variable to Express res.render

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Is it possible to always pass certain variables to `res.render` by default?

More specifically, I'm using the `passport` middleware that populates `req.user` with the current user. I need to access this on every page in my site.

It's tedious to supply it each time -- and if I forget, it appears as if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Can you show us some code and better explain what is going wrong, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution would be to create your own middleware :

```
function userView(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
}

//...

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//...
app.use(userView);
```

For each request, This populates a local variable `user` which is then accessible to the view(s) rendered later in the chain. Activate this middleware **after** the passport one or `req.user` will be undefined.